# Showing that an affine transformation is unique

Tags: linear-algebra

I struggle a bit with this one:

Assume that $\vec{a_1}$, $\vec{a_2}$, $\vec{a_3} \in \mathbb{R}^2$ is not on the same straight line and let $\vec{b_1}$, $\vec{b_2}$, $\vec{b_3}$ be three points in $\mathbb{R}^2$. Show that the affine transformation $\bf{F}$ : $\mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$ defined by $\bf{F}(\vec{a_1}) = \vec{b_1}$, $\bf{F}(\vec{a_2}) = \vec{b_2}$ and $\bf{F}(\vec{a_3}) = \vec{b_3}$ is unique.

I "knot" that is is true, because there are 6 unknown and 6 unique equations. But how do you write a proper proof? (Engligsh is not my natural language, so pardon if there are any errors related to translating ad writing.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since $\vec{a_1}$, $\vec{a_2}$, and $\vec{a_3}$ are not on the same line, they form a 2-simplex (i.e. a non-degenerate triangle). In other words, any point in $\mathbb{R}^2$ can be written as an affine combination of these points. An affine transformation is determined if its action is determined on such a set.

Comment: Does this have to do with linear independence between 2 vectors in $\mathbb{R}^2$? I'm at beginner level, but understand that such two vectors span $\mathbb{R}^2$...

Comment: Yes, it does. Since the three points are not on a line, we may affinely take one of them to  the origin and then the other two would be linearly independent (and hence be a spanning set for $\mathbb{R}^{2}$).